# Excluding multiple folders when copying using powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item

The objective is to copy folders and files from a path to another path using PowerShell. However, I want to exclude certain files and folders from getting copied. I was able to exclude multiple files by adding them to the exclude list

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Exclude "web.config","body.css","Thumbs.db"
```

For excluding folders I added

```
$directory = @("Bin")
?{$_.fullname -notmatch $directory}
```

and the final copy script looks like

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Exclude "Web.config","body.css","Thumbs.db" | ?{$_.fullname -notmatch $directory} | Copy-Item -Force -Destination {if ($_.GetType() -eq [System.IO.FileInfo]) {Join-Path $dest $_.FullName.Substring($source.length)} else {Join-Path $dest $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($source.length)}}
```

This seems to work with a single folder, but when I add multiple folders to the excluded directories it does not seem to work.What can be done to exclude multiple folders?

Comment: .it loooks like u want to use `$_.basename` instead.. `where {$_.basename -notin $dir -and $_.psiscontainer -eq $true}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$source = 'source path'
$dest = 'destination path' 
[string[]]$Excludes = @('file1','file2','folder1','folder2')
$files =  Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Exclude $Excludes | %{ 
$allowed = $true
foreach ($exclude in $Excludes) { 
    if ((Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent) -match $exclude) { 
        $allowed = $false
        break
    }
}
if ($allowed) {
    $_.FullName
}
}
copy-item $source $dest -force -recurse
```

The above code excludes multiple folders listed in $Excludes array and copy the remaining contents to the destination folder

Comment: You have a typo. On the last line you're supposed to have `$files` instead of `$source`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$directory` is an array, you should be looking to match its contents and not itself (it is annoying that powershell lets single-element arrays be treated like their contents).

You can try:

```
?{$directory -contains $_.fullname}
```

Instead of:

```
?{$_.fullname -notmatch $directory}
```

Comment: I assume     ?{$directory -contains $_.fullname} checks if the folder list contains the folders listed in the $directory and hence to exclude them we have to use     ?{$directory -notcontains $_.fullname} . I tried using this but this does not seem to work. It still copies every folder irrespective of contents of $directory

Comment: @stevesimon Yup, you're right, my bad. And shame that it doesn't work! Have you tried individually messing around with name formatting, etc in the powershell command line, rather than running the whole script at once? Perhaps, to help us all out you could post an example of how your $directory file contents look like, in case that's where you made the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$excluded = @("Web.config", "body.css","Thumbs.db")
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Exclude $excluded
```

From the comment, in case you want to exclude folders, you can use something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory -Recurse  | 
      ? { $_.FullName -inotmatch 'foldername' }
```

OR you can check the container first then do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse  | 
      ? { $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.FullName -notmatch 'foldername' }
```

Comment: I am able to exclude files while copying. The issue is with folders and I can't seem to find a way to exclude multiple folders from being copied.