# Powershell: Copy files and folder to a new destination but some files and folder being ignore

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am very new to Powershell and written a script for Our Development Process to copy files and folders from say `Folder1` to `Folder2` but ignore some files and folders.

I am unable to make the below script work.

```
#Exclude list of files and folders to be copied
$excludeFiles = [System.Collections.ArrayList]('*.exe', '*.config', '*.targets', '*.rsp')
$excludeFolders = [System.Collections.ArrayList]('CustomConfiguration', 'abc')

function CopyFilesToFolder ($fromFolder, $toFolder, $ignoreExcludes) {
    $foldersRegex = "($($($excludeFolders.ToArray()) -join "|"))";
    $filesRegex = "($($($excludeFiles.ToArray()) -join "|"))";

    Get-ChildItem -Path $fromFolder -Recurse |
        Where-Object {($_ -ne $null) -and (($ignoreExcludes -eq $false -and $_.fullname -notmatch $foldersRegex) -or ($ignoreExcludes -eq $true)) } |
        Where-Object { ($_ -ne $null) -and (($ignoreExcludes -eq $false -and $_.fullname -notmatch $filesRegex) -or ($ignoreExcludes -eq $true)) } | 
        Copy-Item -Force -Destination {
        if ($_.GetType() -eq [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
            Join-Path $toFolder $_.FullName.Substring($fromFolder.length)
        } 
        else {
            Join-Path $toFolder $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($fromFolder.length)
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S:** Also how can i combine to excludeFiles and excludeFolders lists ??

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318170/excluding-multiple-folders-when-copying-using-powershell

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` has both `-Exclude` and `-Include` as parameters. You can directly avail that.